# Ubuntu 12.10 core different frequencies

Tags: cpufreq

There is a little problem with my CPU, I found some tutorials, how to install Avant Windows Manager, I wanted to change my cpu frequency, I thought it works, but it works only for one core. My CPU is an Intel i5, with 2 cores and 4 threads.

So I used these commands to find out whats going on

```
watch -n 1 cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

CPU*= CPU0 Frequency = Full, CPU1 Frequency = 1,2Ghz, all other CPUs are 1,2GHZ too.

Any idea how to "repair" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a program called [granola](http://personal.grano.la) which is theoretically used for energy saving. Instead of that, I use it for using the full speed of my CPU. To install it, if you're **NOT** using Quantal, just follow the instructions on the download page. Note it's freeware, to download it for free enter just `$0` on the *Custom Ammount*  textbox before downloading.

If you use Quantal, you'll have to download the debs from [here](https://download.miserware.com/linux/deb/ubuntu/quantal/i386/) if you use 32-bit, and from [here](https://download.miserware.com/linux/deb/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/) if you use 64-bit. Download only `granola_5.0.15-0quantal1_amd64.deb` (or replace amd64 with i386 if you're using 32-bit) and `granola-gui_5.0.15-0quantal1_amd64.deb` (also replace amd64 with i386 if you're using 32-bit). Download them on a new subfolder, e.g. **~/Downloads/granola**. Then install them entering a **terminal** and running the following commands:

```
$ cd path/to/folder
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

(replace `path/to/folder` with the relative or absolute path to the folder where you downloaded the debs)

That's all what you have to do. As they have a Quantal repo, I assume they'll be adding it on their automatic installer soon, but when I tried it two days ago, it didn't still work.

After installing Granola, search **Granola** on the dash and open it. Go to **menu - Edit - Preferences** and select **Highest power**. Then just open the **startup applications** configurator, and add a new entry with the name **Granola** and the command **granola**. Just save, and Granola will run each time you boot. You can do `lscpu` the check it. Look at mine before:

```
unrar@catbuntupc:~/bots/git$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Hilo(s) por núcleo:   1
Núcleo(s) por zócalo:2
Socket(s):             1
Nodo(s) NUMA:          1
ID del vendedor:       GenuineIntel
Familia de CPU:        6
Modelo:                15
Stepping:              13
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              3989.98
caché L1d:            32K
caché L1i:            32K
caché L2:             2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

And after:

```
unrar@catbuntupc:~/bots/git$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Hilo(s) por núcleo:   1
Núcleo(s) por zócalo:2
Socket(s):             1
Nodo(s) NUMA:          1
ID del vendedor:       GenuineIntel
Familia de CPU:        6
Modelo:                15
Stepping:              13
CPU MHz:               2000.000
BogoMIPS:              3989.98
caché L1d:            32K
caché L1i:            32K
caché L2:             2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
```

Comment: works like a charm. +1 for solid install instructions